# Run a powershell script on a remote system with elevated permissions to enable remoting

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use the following code to copy a PowerShell script to remote windows 7 machine; run it with elevated privileges on this machine to enable remoting on that system.

It is copying the script file to the remote system but it is not executing the command in the remote PowerShell session because of the empty `$command` variable (the second line in the script below is not working).

```
Copy-Item -Path C:\users\user1\Myscript.ps1 -Destination \\some-computer\c$\Myscript.ps1

$command = PowerShell.exe -NoProfile -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell.exe -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""C:\Myscript.ps1""' -Verb RunAs > C:\PS-result1.txt}"

$cmd = "CMD.EXE /c "+$command

Invoke-WmiMethod -class Win32_process -name Create -ArgumentList $cmd -ComputerName "some-computer"

Start-Sleep -s 8

Get-Content \\some-computer\C$\PS-result1.txt
```

Is it possible to accomplish this?
Thanks,

Answer (score -1):

Using WMI to call CMD to call PowerShell to call Start-Process to call PowerShell again? That seems a little complicated.

Try something much simpler:

```
$command = "PowerShell.exe ""C:\Myscript.ps1"" > ""C:\PS-result1.txt"""
Invoke-WmiMethod -class Win32_process -name Create -ArgumentList $command -ComputerName "some-computer"
```

Comment: This does not appear to start the script as an _elevated_ process, which appears to be what the querent desires, based on the original code. Note that `$command` contains the `-Verb RunAs` parameter to the `Start-Process`.